# Separating nested RDP sessions

Tags: remote-desktop

I have to use nested RDP sessions to access servers.

Whenever I open an RDP session, I get a tab on the top of the window.  From that server, when I go to the next server, the tab appears but it appears underneath the tab for the current session.  It is always a struggle to shutdown the second session - somehow unpinning doesn't work on a nested session.  Either that or there is a massive delay before the tab unpins itself. This is on W10.

I remember from about two years ago someone showing me a nested session where the tabs appeared side-by-side.  This guy was nested 3 deep and there were 3 tabs on the top.  It was W8 but I don't know what the other two were.  How do you do that with RDP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpinning has always worked for me. You can also click and drag the tab from side to side so that they don't overlap.

Comment: Never thought of dragging them.